# KnockoutJS freeze in Chrome during unloading

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I use **ko.mapping** pluging for binding a complex model (f.e. Project having list of branches, each having list of Tasks). Data are refreshed let's say every 10 seconds with ajax request and updated by the following function: **ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);**

After several updates and leaving page (or page Refresh) in Chrome is one core of my CPU busy and page leaving takes about 10s to a minute. Situation in Firefox looks better, but observed rarely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the debugger to see how many branches are in your Project object when the CPU is getting hammered? It'd be worth checking that mapping is updating the branches, rather than creating new ones with each update.